# Fetch data from asp.net using backbone

Tags: asp.net, jquery, backbone.js

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home.aspx/loadSB",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        for (i = 0; i < msg.d.length; i++) {
            $('#sidebar ul').append('<li class="inactive"><a>' + msg.d[i].Title + ' </a></li>');
        }
    }
});
```

I go through this
https://github.com/kjbekkelund/writings/blob/master/published/understanding-backbone.md
and 
https://gist.github.com/ryandotsmith/1655019
tutorial and create a backbone as below, but is not working well as the model did not fetch data from asp.net, which part goes wrong? I still new to backbone

```
Menu = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function (data) { return data; }
});

MenuCol = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Menu,
    url: "Home.aspx/loadSB",
    parse: function (response) { return response.rows; }
});

MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('add', this.appendMenu, this);
    },
    appendMenu: function (msg) {
        for (i = 0; i < msg.d.length; i++) {
            this.$('ul').append('<li class="inactive"><a>' + msg.d[i].Title + ' </a></li>');
        }
    }
});

 var mc = new MenuCol();
 //mc.fetch();
 //Update1:
 new MenuView({ el: $('#sidebar'), collection: mc });
```

**Update 1:**
I had play around with fetch, but still not working well,

```
Menu = Backbone.Model.extend({});

MenuCol = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Menu,
    url: "Home.aspx/loadSB",
});

var test = new MenuCol();
test.fetch();
```

It did not return the data that I want, instead of, it display the interface that my screen have
[image]

If i using the jquery.ajax without backbone, it return the json data to me, which part goes wrong? Any guide will be great
[image]

**Update 2:**

Ok, I had change the "fetch", and now I able to see the json data passing into backbone

```
var test = new MenuCol();
test.fetch({ type: 'POST', contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8" });
```

Comment: Is your `mc.fetch` succeeding? I don't see anywhere that you've instantiated your view, do you have a `new MenuView({ collection: mc })` anywhere?

Comment: I had try to use fetch and then new MenuView, it still not success, I still new to backbone, so still figuring out how to actually get the model to store the data pass from asp.net

Comment: You'll still need an `mc.fetch()` in there somewhere, that will pull data down from the server. `fetch` is an AJAX call though so you'll have all the usual async issues to deal with but binding to collection events should take care of most of that.

Comment: Ok, I try it out, although have no idea where to add, try to browse different web to figure it out, thanks

Comment: Model return value of 0, still cant puzzle it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I had solved the problem,

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function () {
Menu = Backbone.Model.extend({});

MenuCol = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Menu,
    url: "Home.aspx/loadSB",
});

MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('add', _.bind(this.AppendMenu, this));
    },
    AppendMenu: function (msg) {
        var feed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg));
        for (var i = 0; i < feed.d.length; i++) {
            this.$('ul').append('<li class="inactive"><a>' + feed.d[i].Title + ' </a></li>');
        }
    }
});

var test = new MenuCol();
test.fetch({ type: 'POST', contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8" });
new MenuView({ el: $('#sidebar'), collection: test })

});
```

by changing the fetch type to "POST" and  contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", finally i manage to populate web with the data I want